# Why are certificates expiration time different everytime I check for them?

Tags: python, ssl, x509certificate

I want to get the expiration time of some certificates,beacause I want to write a program to notify when the certificate about to expire.

But when I run the code, I found sometimes the results (expiration time) are different.It is not nowtime is different,there is a lot of difference in numbers,like 1 and 100.You can see the picture.I guess the process of getting certificate is wrong but I can't find where is it.Besides,it is not the problem of timezones.

```
for length_list_domain in range(0,len(all_domains['HostedZones'])):

    HostedZoneId = all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Id']
    sub_domains = client.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId = HostedZoneId)     
    for length_list_subdomain in range(0,len(sub_domains['ResourceRecordSets'])):

        try:
            if all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Name'] in null_domain:
                break
            else:

                hostname = sub_domains['ResourceRecordSets'][length_list_subdomain]['Name']
                port = 443
                conn = ssl.create_connection((hostname,port))
                context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
                sock = context.wrap_socket(conn,server_hostname = hostname)
                certificate = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(sock.getpeercert(True))
                x509 = reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,certificate)


                expire_time_first = x509.get_notAfter()[:-1].decode()



                now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

                expire_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(expire_time_first,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

                remain_time = expire_time - now
                print(remain_time.days)

                remain_time_list[all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Name']] = remain_time.days

                break
        except:
            pass

return remain_time_list
```

Then I tried threading lock to solve this problem,but it didn't work.

```
    mutex = threading.Lock()
for length_list_domain in range(0,len(all_domains['HostedZones'])):

    HostedZoneId = all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Id']
    sub_domains = client.list_resource_record_sets(HostedZoneId = HostedZoneId)     
    for length_list_subdomain in range(0,len(sub_domains['ResourceRecordSets'])):

        try:
            if all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Name'] in null_domain:
                break
            else:
                mutex.acquire()
                hostname = sub_domains['ResourceRecordSets'][length_list_subdomain]['Name']
                port = 443
                conn = ssl.create_connection((hostname,port))
                context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
                sock = context.wrap_socket(conn,server_hostname = hostname)
                certificate = ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(sock.getpeercert(True))
                x509 = reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(reqs.OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,certificate)


                expire_time_first = x509.get_notAfter()[:-1].decode()

                mutex.release()

                now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

                expire_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(expire_time_first,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

                remain_time = expire_time - now
                print(remain_time.days)

                remain_time_list[all_domains['HostedZones'][length_list_domain]['Name']] = remain_time.days

                break
        except:
            pass

return remain_time_list
```

[The results are as this picture,the number is the day of remain time(expired time - nowtime)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luboc.png)

I use x509.get_subject and reqs.get_alt_subject to get information and I just run the first domain and It seems that another domain will appear,why?

[the results of the first domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvLIF.png)

Comment: Maybe the certificates are being rotated (i.e. one of multiple certificates being used at random).

Comment: "I found sometimes the results(expire time)are different" then show them! Also, why it is important? Besides that, of course as with anything related to timestamps, be particularly cautious about timezones and things like that. Also saying "I tried X but it didn't work" is not proper troubleshooting you need to show exactly what you did and the error you get and what you expected instead.

Comment: You are printing the difference between the current time and the expiration time.  You are performing a different calculation every time you run the script because your time has changed.

Comment: @ Patrick Mevzek I'm sorry,i am a fresh,thank u very much! I changed my problem

Comment: @Jason  sorry, I didn't show my problem obviously,you can see my pic.

Comment: @ Ahmad It seems not this problem

Comment: emmm,I found where is wrong,my boss told me some subdomain has wrong certificate....